# Error 404 when accessing website by traffic manager URL

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Hi, I am trying to configure a basic traffic manager on my azure account. But I always got 404 not found when I using the traffic manager URL.

I have two app service for the TM endpoints:

`1. xxxus.azurewebsites.net
2. xxxeu.azurewebsites.net`

TM Url is:

`xxxtm.trafficmanage.net`

I was able to use www.whatsmydns.net to check what the tm is heading to.

[image: Image 1]

But when I use the TM url, I got this:

[image: Image 2]

Did anyone has the same issue? Looking forward to your help

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the exact same thing and just found the solution - the app service plan needs to be at least a standard SKU.  I was using a free tier, and that was causing my 404.

From [Microsoft's Traffic Manager documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types)

> Only Web Apps at the 'Standard' SKU or above are eligible for use with Traffic Manager. Attempts to add a Web App of a lower SKU fail. Downgrading the SKU of an existing Web App results in Traffic Manager no longer sending traffic to that Web App.

Comment: This is SO ... I have run 24 hours on a D1. I created another traffic manager, and started to see this. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you could not add web apps from different subscriptions to the same traffic manager configuration since It is not possible to use Web Apps from multiple subscriptions with the same domain name. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#can-i-use-traffic-manager-with-endpoints-from-multiple-subscriptions). You can check this on your side. If so, you can remove one website from your endpoint, then add the website to the same subscriptions.

Moreover, the 404 error always happen due to the domain name could not be resolved by its IP address. It may be one of the following reasons:

- The custom domain configured is missing an A record and/or a CNAME record.
- The browser client has cached the old IP address of your domain. Clear the cache and test DNS resolution again. On a Windows machine, you clear the cache with ipconfig /flushdns.

You can follow the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/quickstart-create-traffic-manager-profile) to create a Traffic Manager profile, then follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-testing-settings) to verify your traffic manager settings.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue. My problem is one of my app service is a free tier, so  I scaled it up to standard one. And delete my traffic manager and reinstalled and add the service endpoint again, the issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. Nslookup will take you to the right web app but the browser will show 404. Changing the app service plan to 'Standard' SKU fixed it for me.